# How can I update maps after updating features in cluster?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to update features in the cluster when I change the value of the price. Got no problem, to put them in the cluster but for some reason, I don't know why it still loading previous features and not the new one.

I've looked for some question which could have help but none is helping.  Tried map.updateSize(), clear the layers and then add the features, map.renderSynch().

Creating my features in my tabs :

```
for (var i =0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (typebien == "FC") {                  
          features_FC.push(createCluster(typebien, title, latitude,longitude, nb, ville, secteur, adresse,nom));
     }else if (typebien == "IM") {                       
          features_IM.push(createCluster(typebien, title, latitude,longitude, nb, ville, secteur, adresse,nom));
     }
```

creating the vector source and the layer

```
var sourceIM = new ol.source.Vector({
   features: features_IM
});

var clusterSourceFC = new ol.source.Cluster({
   distance: 30,
   source: sourceFC
});
```

adding it to the map

It has shown all the features as it supposed to do but then when I change the price values from a slider it still shows the same features which are not possible. Any idea on how I can update the map to have the new features in the cluster ?

Edit :
I'm actually here my map and cluster is showing really well but when i'm starting to change the value of the price it still showing the same numbers of clusters.
Tried clusterSourceFC.refresh({force:true}) but still doing nothing

image of my map (since i don't have enough reputation to post it)
https://zupimages.net/up/19/18/co65.png

Comment: Can you confirm your cluster's source shouldn't be sourceIM ?

Comment: I'm using 8 diiferents sources clusters

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your layer's source with `clusterSourceFC.refresh({force:true});`

But, without knowing what are `features_FC`, `features_IM` and the function `createCluster` it's quit difficult to get your problem

Comment: Oh yeah i'm sorry
features_FC and features_IM are tabs where are my differents clusters. So i'm putting my features in them and then create the cluster source and the layer to add them to my map
And gonna try your solution right now thx !